# Return type from operator overloading gets lost

Tags: c++

```
#include <memory>

struct Class
{
    Class(int _ptr) : ptr(std::make_unique<int>(_ptr)), f(0) {}
    Class(float _f) : f(_f) {}

    float f;
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;

    Class operator+=(const Class& rv)
    {
        return Class((int)25);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Class a(3.5f);
    Class b(2.4f);

    a += b; 
}
```

Here, `a += b;` calls the overloaded operator, returns an instance of `Class` with an initialized pointer. Yet in the end of the program, `a` is still equal to its previous value `{ f=3.50000 ptr=empty }`

How do I properly set `a` equal to the return type of the overloaded operator? (in this case: `{f = 0.00 ptr=unique_ptr 25}`)

Comment: Your overloaded `operator+=` doesn't make much sense, since it doesn't modify the current object, only returns a new one

Comment: @UnholySheep sense apart, is there a way to make it work?

Comment: you could actually modify the member instead of creating a new instance. `operator+=` is not supposed to create a new instance

Comment: `_ptr = std::make_unique<int>(24); f = 0; return *this;`?

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you ever feel the need to do a C-style cast (like e.g. `(int)25`) then you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong. In this case a cast isn't even needed, as `25` is in itself an `int` value. You're casting an `int` to an `int`.

Comment: what Jarod42 said and return type should be `Class&`

Comment: You probably want `std::variant` in your example as `float` and `int` seems exclusive.

Comment: As for your problem, all assignment operators should modify `this` object, and return a reference to `*this`.